# When random number hits certain value, h1 or button should change color

Tags: javascript, random, parsefloat

I made a random color generator and while it generates the random colors and displays the numbers, when it gets very dark on the page I wanted the h1 to become white and the button to become black if it became very bright.

```
const button = document.getElementById('button');
const h1 = document.getElementById('h1');

button.addEventListener('click', function (){
    const r = Math.floor(Math.random() * 255);
    const g = Math.floor(Math.random() * 255);
    const b = Math.floor(Math.random() * 255);
    const newColor = `rgb(${r}, ${g}, ${b})`;
    document.body.style.backgroundColor = newColor;
    h1.innerText = newColor;
});

button.addEventListener('click', function (){
    if(parseFloat(r >= 150 || g >= 150 || b >= 150)) {
        document.button.style.backgroundColor = '#000';
        document.button.style.color = '#fff';
    } else if(parseFloat(r >= 60 || g >= 60 || b >= 60)) {
        document.h1.style.color = '#fff';
    }
});
```

I think there is an issue with my parseFloat but I am unsure. I think the issue is that the number becomes a string and isn't converted back properly?

Right now my code just does not respond to the second portion where I ask the 'if' statements.

Comment: Put everything in the same function. The variables are local to the first function, so you can't access them in the second function.

Comment: It's not clear what you're trying to do with `parseFloat()`. The value of the condition is `true` or `false`, not a number.

Comment: Isn't the second function getting errors because of the undefined variables?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to do everything in one function, because the variables aren't visible in the second function.

There's also no need to call `parseFloat()`. You already have numbers  in those variables.

`document.button` and `document.h1` should just be `button` and `h1`.

```js
button.addEventListener('click', function() {
  const r = Math.floor(Math.random() * 255);
  const g = Math.floor(Math.random() * 255);
  const b = Math.floor(Math.random() * 255);

  const newColor = `rgb(${r}, ${g}, ${b})`;
  document.body.style.backgroundColor = newColor;
  h1.innerText = newColor;
  if (r >= 150 || g >= 150 || b >= 150) {
    button.style.backgroundColor = '#000';
    button.style.color = '#fff';
  } else if (r >= 60 || g >= 60 || b >= 60) {
    h1.style.color = '#fff';
  }
});
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I was misunderstanding how to use things. You fixed it!